# Count and append table column in Jquery

Tags: jquery, count, append

I'm having below html structure,

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>...</rd>
        <td>...</rd>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm trying to include below before table ends,

```
<tfoot>
   <tr>
     <th>...</th>
     <th>...</th>
   </tr>
</tfoot>
```

One logic here is, i need to include only 2 two columns (2 "th" tags), because top i have only two columns.

So is there any way to count and append equal table columns dymanically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use length to get the number of columns. Here is my answer variant

```
var noOfColumns = $('#myTable tbody tr td').length;
$('<tfoot><tr></tr></tfoot>').appendTo('#myTable');
for(var i = 1; i <= noOfColumns; i++){
  $('#myTable tfoot tr').append('th');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it

```
$html = '<tfoot>
   <tr>
     <th>...</th>
     <th>...</th>
   </tr>
</tfoot>';
Try using $('#myTable').append($html);
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/95/)</kbd>

use [**.append()**](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
$("#myTable").append("<tfoot><tr><th>foot1</th><th>footer2</th></tr></tfoot>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jQ for this.

to count child elements of your tr tag u should use a line like this

```
$count = $("#myTable tbody tr td").length;
```

BUT THIS CODE WILL GIVE YOU THE COUNT OF ALL THE TD ELEMENTS IN THE TABLE
i mean if you have 2 tr elements containing 2 td each the selector length above will return 4 instead of 2

You can fix this by giving your tr elements an id then selecting them and counting their childs or td elements inside.

and for appending your footer u could use this.

```
$("#myTable").append("<tfoot><tr>");
for(i=1,i<$count,i++){
     $("#myTable tfoot").append("<th>...</th>")
}
$("#myTable").append("</tr></tfoot>");
```

Hope this helps!